# seaborn fit lines into multi-facetted plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

for the following data,

```
import pandas as pd
# sample data set
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'year': [ 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10,
             15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20,
             20, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30],
    'month': [1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 6, 6, 12, 12, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 6, 6, 12, 12, 1, 1, 3,
              3, 6, 6, 12, 12, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 6, 6, 12, 12, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 6,
              6, 12, 12],
    'mid': [0.825, 0.83, 0.85, 0.935, 0.96, 1.055, 1.12, 1.305, 1.38, 1.235, 
            1.25, 1.345, 1.34, 1.34, 1.455, 1.46, 1.635, 1.65, 1.375, 1.39,
            1.475, 1.47, 1.585, 1.59, 1.785, 1.8, 1.535, 1.54, 1.635, 1.63,
            1.62, 1.755, 1.74, 1.96, 1.95, 1.695, 1.7, 1.71, 1.805, 1.8, 1.79,
            1.925, 1.91, 2.12, 2.1],
    'source': ['wood', 'metal', 'water', 'wood', 'water', 'wood', 'water', 
               'wood', 'water', 'wood', 'water', 'wood', 'metal', 'water',
               'wood', 'water', 'wood', 'water', 'wood', 'water', 'wood',
               'water', 'wood', 'water', 'wood', 'water', 'wood', 'water',
               'wood', 'metal', 'water', 'wood', 'water', 'wood', 'water',
               'wood', 'metal', 'water', 'wood', 'metal','water', 'wood',
               'water', 'wood', 'water']})
```

a series of 5 `scipy` [cubic spline](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.CubicSpline.html) objects by `'year'` is calculated

```
from scipy.interpolate import CubicSpline
def spline3(df, col1, col2):
    x, y = df[col1].values, df[col2].values
    cs = CubicSpline(x, y, bc_type='natural')
    return cs

avg_df = df.groupby(['year','month'])['mid'].mean().reset_index()

# indexed series of spline obj
splines = avg_df.groupby('year').apply(spline3, 'month', 'mid')
```

so i could plot the fitted curve for a single `'year'` group:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6.5, 4))
x = df.groupby('year').get_group(5)['month']
y = df.groupby('year').get_group(5)['mid']
ax.plot(x, y, 'o', label='data')
ax.plot(x, splines[5](x) , label="S")
```

[image: single_fit]

How to fit all 5 splines in the facetted `seaborn relplot` on the original data below?

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.relplot(x='month', y='mid', hue='source', data=df,
            palette=['green','orange', 'purple'],
            col='year', col_wrap=5, legend=True, height=6, aspect=.5,
            style='source')
```

[image: relplot]

Comment: Is there a reason to use seaborn? If you managed to implement your plot for one graph using matplotlib, why not plot a figure with five axes objects and plot each graph into a subplot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could loop through the subplots and draw the splines:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
from scipy.interpolate import CubicSpline

def spline3(df, col1, col2):
    x, y = df[col1].values, df[col2].values
    return CubicSpline(x, y, bc_type='natural')

df = pd.DataFrame({'year': [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30],
                   'month': [1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 6, 6, 12, 12, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 6, 6, 12, 12, 1, 1, 3, 3, 6, 6, 12, 12, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 6, 6, 12, 12, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 6, 6, 12, 12],
                   'mid': [0.825, 0.83, 0.85, 0.935, 0.96, 1.055, 1.12, 1.305, 1.38, 1.235, 1.25, 1.345, 1.34, 1.34, 1.455, 1.46, 1.635, 1.65, 1.375, 1.39, 1.475, 1.47, 1.585, 1.59, 1.785, 1.8, 1.535, 1.54, 1.635, 1.63, 1.62, 1.755, 1.74, 1.96, 1.95, 1.695, 1.7, 1.71, 1.805, 1.8, 1.79, 1.925, 1.91, 2.12, 2.1],
                   'source': ['wood', 'metal', 'water', 'wood', 'water', 'wood', 'water', 'wood', 'water', 'wood', 'water', 'wood', 'metal', 'water', 'wood', 'water', 'wood', 'water', 'wood', 'water', 'wood', 'water', 'wood', 'water', 'wood', 'water', 'wood', 'water', 'wood', 'metal', 'water', 'wood', 'water', 'wood', 'water', 'wood', 'metal', 'water', 'wood', 'metal', 'water', 'wood', 'water', 'wood', 'water']})
avg_df = df.groupby(['year', 'month'])['mid'].mean().reset_index()

# indexed series of spline obj
splines = avg_df.groupby('year').apply(spline3, 'month', 'mid')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6.5, 4))
x = df.groupby('year').get_group(5)['month']
y = df.groupby('year').get_group(5)['mid']
ax.plot(x, y, 'o', label='data')
ax.plot(x, splines[5](x), label="S")

g = sns.relplot(x='month', y='mid', hue='source', data=df,
                palette=['green', 'orange', 'purple'],
                col='year', col_wrap=5, legend=True, height=6, aspect=.5,
                style='source')
for ax, year, spline in zip(g.axes.flat, g.col_names, splines):
    x = df[df['year'] == year]['month']
    ax.plot(x, spline(x))
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(3))
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.relplot with added splines]

Answer (score 1):

I understand the question of the intention to add a spline line to each seaborn graph, and I created it using your code.

```
yy = []
xx = []
for i in [5,10,15,20,30]:
    x = df.groupby('year').get_group(i)['month']
    s = splines[i](x)
    xx.append(x)
    yy.append(s)

import seaborn as sns
g = sns.relplot(x='month', y='mid', hue='source', data=df,
            palette=['green','orange', 'purple'],
            col='year', col_wrap=5, legend=True, height=6, aspect=.5,
            style='source')

#print(g)
axes = g.fig.axes
for k,ax in enumerate(axes):
    ax.plot(xx[k],yy[k], c='C1')

plt.show()
```

[image]